# thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x41736e30)

Tags: android, google-calendar-api, android-calendar

```
public class CreateEventTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {
    com.google.api.services.calendar.Calendar mService;
    java.util.Calendar calendar, calendar1;
    String EventTitle;
    String useremail;
    String location;

CreateEventTask(Calendar mService, String EvTitle, java.util.Calendar cal, java.util.Calendar cal1, String Uemail, String loc) {
        this.mService = mService;
        EventTitle = EvTitle;
        calendar = cal;
        calendar1 = cal1;
        useremail = Uemail;
        location = loc;
    }

@Override
protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
    addCalendarEvent();
    return null;
}

  public void addCalendarEvent() {
        Event event = new Event()
                .setSummary(EventTitle)
                .setLocation(location)
                .setDescription("My efforts.");

        DateTime startDateTime = new DateTime(calendar.getTime());
        EventDateTime start = new EventDateTime().setDateTime(startDateTime);
        event.setStart(start);

        DateTime endDateTime = new DateTime(calendar1.getTime());
        EventDateTime end = new EventDateTime().setDateTime(endDateTime);

        event.setEnd(end);
        Log.d("Event stored", event.getEnd().getDateTime().toString());
        String calendarId = "primary";
        try {
            mService.events().insert(calendarId, event).execute();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

My this code creates event one day event without any error but
if for example an event exist on 4 march 2016 
  While creating event start date 3 march 2016 to 5 march 2016 
it gives following exception please help

```
  02-21 00:31:54.534  14067-14187/com.example.meetingplanner W/dalvikvm﹕ threadid=13: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x41736e30)
        02-21 00:31:54.544  14067-14187/com.example.meetingplanner E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: AsyncTask #2
            Process: com.example.meetingplanner, PID: 14067
            java.lang.RuntimeException: An error occured while executing doInBackground()
                    at android.os.AsyncTask$3.done(AsyncTask.java:300)
                    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.finishCompletion(FutureTask.java:355)
                    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.setException(FutureTask.java:222)
                    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:242)
                    at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:231)
                    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1112)
                    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:587)
                    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:864)
             Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
                    at com.example.meetingplanner.CreateEventTask.addCalendarEvent(CreateEventTask.java:52)
                    at com.example.meetingplanner.CreateEventTask.doInBackground(CreateEventTask.java:31)
                    at com.example.meetingplanner.CreateEventTask.doInBackground(CreateEventTask.java:13)
                    at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:288)
                    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:237)
                    at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:231)
                    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1112)
                    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:587)
                    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:864)
```

Comment: What's `at com.example.meetingplanner.CreateEventTask.addCalendarEvent(CreateEventTask.java:52)` and have you checked is it null?

Comment: its that line 
mService.events().insert(calendarId, event).execute();

Comment: There is an `NPE` at that point in your `AsyncTask`. Can you post that bit of code...maybe a few lines before and after `com.example.meetingplanner.CreateEventTask.addCalendarEvent(CreateEventTask.java‌​:52)` inside your `AsyncTask` that is...

Comment: I have updated the code and provided the whole class
and it is called by new CreateEventTask(mService, eventTitle, calendar, calendar1, creatorEmail, Location).execute();

Answer (score 1):

Something is null, and your best bet is to fire up a debugger, put a breakpoint in addCalendarEvent line 52, and check what. Options are:

- mService
- mService.events()
- mService.events().insert(calendarId, event)

Or break it up into multiple lines and check for nullity.

Answer (score 0):

Move `try {` to start of function `addCalendarEvent` and use `catch(Exception | IOException e ){e.printstacktrace();}` with it.